# JSNI GWT jquery

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have a file jQuery to create the flip card effect and I changed it to JSNI, use native function but error. I don't know what's wrong. Can anybody help me?
This is my native function:

```
public native void flip() /*-{
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-list-example div div.back').hide().css('left', 0);

    function mySideChange(front) {
        if (front) {
            $(this).parent().find('div.front').show();
            $(this).parent().find('div.back').hide();

        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('div.front').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('div.back').show();
        }
    }

    $('#nav-list-example div').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 250, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 500, {sideChange: mySideChange});
        }
    );
});
         }-*/;
```

Answer (score 7):

[JSNI 101](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing): `$wnd.$($doc).ready(function($) {…`

Using `$` as the argument to the callback function should allow using `$` inside the function instead of `$wnd.$`.

Comment: (Under GWTP) Any idea why I had to use ViewImpl#onAttach instead of $.ready?  See Answer to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35394537/1357094.  Thanks

Comment: It now appears my Answer (linked in above comment) is that GWTP lazy loading means DOM can be loaded before all Views/Presenters have been loaded.  So for GWT, ViewImpl#onAttach is necessary instead of $.ready

Comment: This is true of all GWT apps, as onModuleLoad is called no earlier then DOMContentLoad, and possibly after.

Comment: OK.  So in that case, how is using $.ready() expected to have all Elements in DOM when its callback is called, if onModuleLoad() is important for full DOM element readiness?  Unless I'm missing something?  The idea here is to ensure an Element is in the DOM before doing a $ jQuery selection on it?

Answer (score 4):

I always use this:

```
$wnd.jQuery($doc).ready(function(){});
```

Inside function, you can make a 'alias' to jQuery, e.g.:

```
function(){
  var _ = $wnd.jQuery;
  // go on....
}
```

Hope it helps :)

---

BTW: this is how we did it in GWT-Bootstrap.