# GWT Jquery Mobile Refresh list view

Tags: gwt, jquery-mobile, jsni

I'm adding some ListView items using AJAX in GWT.

If I call using the console in Chrome the following it works fine.

> $( "#basket" ).listview( "refresh" );

If I call the following function in Java nothing happens:

```
public static native void refreshListView()/*-{
    $wnd.$( "#basket" ).listview( "refresh" );
}-*/;
```

Is there something wrong with my JSNI syntax in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the refreshViewList before the widget was loaded properly.
This works:

```
item.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

      @Override
      public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
          JQMUtil.refreshListView();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817236/jsni-gwt-jquery#)

```
public static native void refreshListView()/*-{
$wnd.$($doc).ready(function($) { 
   $( "#basket" ).listview( "refresh" );
});
}-*/;
```